# is there tree with 8 vertices, diameter 5, and radius 4?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

is there a tree with vertices 8 and diameter 5 with radius 4
I think this is possible because i can draw it,

the tree height is 4, in height 1 there are 2 nodes,in height 2 there are 3 nodes, in height 2,3,4 there is 1 node,

is this right? 
is there other way to know tree is possible or not beside drawing it?

[image]

Comment: Hint: It isn't possible.

Comment: Do you have a proof of it? I appear to have a graph that might work, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around the definition of diameter and radius.

Comment: Okay, I figured out why it's impossible. Thank you.

Comment: @David can you explain what is the reason if it isnt possible ?

Comment: In a path of length 5, it is not possible to make the third vertex with eccentricity more than 3.

Comment: Take for example, the eccentricity of $C$ is 3, which is the radius of the graph.

Comment: @David ah i see in my graph the radius is 3 while diam is 5?

Comment: Yep, that is right!

Comment: @David is there formula to know if tree exist or not beside drawing?